# Which MySQL database tables contain the data for the stores in Magento 1.x?

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I would like to retrieve the following data via MySQL for each store, so that I can build a data structure in my PHP code:

```
READ in from MySQL:
  3. all active stores:
     3.1 store package (enterprise)  
     3.2 magento default theme (default)        
     3.3 store default theme  
     3.4 store layout
     3.5 store templates
```

I tried to do a diff before changing admin data for a store, but the memory limit was reached when comparing the 2 MySQL dump files before and after the change.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Store information can be found in

```
select * from core_store
```

Changes from the current design can be found in

```
SELECT * FROM design_change
```

Package/theme/layout information is configuration, and can be found in

```
select * from core_config_data
```

If a value isn't set for a configuration item, there won't be a value in this table.  Default configuration values are kept in each module's `config.xml`, under the `<default />` node.

At the risk of shilling (it's my product), a tool like [Commerce Bug](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug) can quickly list out the collection objects Magento uses to fetch these in the admin, which can quickly point the way toward the database tables you need.

Comment: +1 for Commerce Bug shilling, I only use it about 3% of the time but it can really save your butt 3% of the time.